# How to grep a pattern for each and every element of an array

Tags: perl

I have buffered a complete file in an array soc_data(@soc_data).Now i am trying to grep a pattern in each and every line of the file or we can say each and every element of the array .

i have used this .But this is not working properly and flag is always 1 , but it should toggle as the pattern is not present in every line but only in few lines.

```
my $flag = 0 ;
if(grep("  ".$val." ".$instance, @soc_data)){
  $flag = 1 ;
}
else {
 $flag = 0 ;
}
```

Please suggest the way to do it and the mistake that i am doing here .

Comment: Of interest: https://perlmaven.com/how-to-grep-a-file-using-perl I suspect there are similar SO Qs as well.

Answer (score 5):

It cannot toggle with the code you have written. Your code checks if there is any occurrence of the pattern in the array. [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) will look at each line (element in the array) in turn, and return a list of the ones that match the pattern. Then your flag is set and you are done.

```
my @list = ( 1 .. 20 );
my @match = grep /3/, @list;
print "@match";

# 3 13
```

If you want to do each line individually, you need to loop over the array yourself in an outer loop, and then do a match. No need for `grep` then.

```
foreach my $line (@soc_data) {
    my $flag = 0;
    $flag = 1 if $line =~ m/  $val $instance/; # you might want to use \s

    # do things with $flag
}
```

Comment: Re "*`my $flag = 0;  $flag = 1 if $line =~ m/  $val $instance/;`*", or just `my $flag = $line =~ /  $val $instance/;`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for adding that. I had decided not to put it in the answer because OP had the `if` construct and i wanted to stick with it. It felt somehow that they'll be more comfortable with it than with just taking the return value of the match.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is often used to apply regular expressions to a list of strings, but the `grep` in Perl is more general than that, and you must explicitly use a regular expression if that's what you want to use `grep` for. Compare:

```
@list = (7,8,9,10);
print grep /1/, @list;        # 10 -- only "10" matches /1/
print grep 1, @list;          # 7 8 9 10, EXPR is always true
```

Your use of `grep` is more like the 2nd case. The first argument to `grep` is just a non-empty and non-zero scalar, so it is always "true" and the return value of `grep` is always every element in the list. I suspect you want something like

```
if (grep / $val $instance/, @soc_data) { ... }
```

or if `$val` and `$instance` might have regexp metacharacters,

```
if (grep / \Q$val\E \Q$instance\E/, @soc_data) { ... }
```

(I don't really know what you mean by "toggling", so I probably haven't properly addressed that part of your question)